# Difference between Hirose U.FL and IPEX connectors

Tags: antenna, wireless, modem

Both these connectors are used to connect antenna to Mini PCI cards.

Wikipedia does not explain the difference between those naming issues:

> U.FL, IPEX, IPAX, IPX,[1] AMC, MHF and UMCC is a miniature RF connector for high-frequency signals up to 6 GHz manufactured by Hirose Electric Group[2] and others. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirose_U.FL

An acquaintance told me it's just a difference in the brand name. IPEX connectors are a bit cheaper and easier to obtain than U.FL (at least in China, it seems). Is it true? I cannot find any relevant information on the net or in the relevant datasheets.

Thanks.

Comment: Not just a difference in name, but the differences are so minor that they can be considered insignificant. The IPEX is a line/brand, and the IPEX MHF is the closest to the Hiroshi U.FL.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, IPEX is a line/type of connectors made by LTI (LightHorse Technologies Inc). As @Passerby pointed out, IPEX mhf connector is the equivalent of Hiroshi U.fl (according to this website they are 100% compatible: http://www.wellshow.com/rf-connectors/mini-connector/ipex-mhf-connector/)

Answer (score 20):

Short answer: It's a brand thing.

Long answer: All refer to micro RF coaxial connectors for 0-6Ghz applications based on the Hirose U.FL-series design.

U.FL = U.FL series from Hirose Electric Group

Specs: hirose.com/product/en/products/U.FL/

IPEX = MHF series from I-PEX Connectors

Specs: i-pex.com/Products/Micro-RF-Coax-Connector

Ya got me on IPAX...

IPX = IPX series from LightHorse Technologies

Specs: rfconnector.com/ipx-connectors.php

AMC = Amphenol Micro Coaxial connector series from Amphenol RF

Specs: amphenolrf.com/connectors/amc.html

MHF = MHF series from I-PEX Connectors

Specs: i-pex.com/Products/Micro-RF-Coax-Connector

UMCC = Ultraminiature Coax Connector and Cable Assembly Style A Series from Tyco Electronics

Specs: te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Catalog+Section%7F1307191_UMCC_Connectors%7F0307%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_CS_1307191_UMCC_Connectors_0307.pdf%7F1307191

All claim 100% compatibility with Hirose u.fl