# What is the name of antenna and connector in the image

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, antenna, embedded, gps

Below is the image of a GPS module. I have highlighted the antenna in the yellow box:

[image]

What is the name of the antenna in the yellow box (Question 1) ? Is the **type** of this antenna `APM 2.5` (Question 2) ? What does APM stands for in `APM 2.5` (Question 3) ?

Is the connector of the antenna `IPX`? There are different sizes of `IPX`, what are they ? Is `IPX` connector also known as `UFL` (Question 4)?

I would appreciate answers to any/some/ all of above related questions.

Comment: plug looks like `U.FL` but yeah `IPX` looks similar.

Comment: Informally everyone calls these U.FL which is actually the Hirose part number. But if you call it something else, nobody understands what you refer to.

Comment: They don’t seem to indicate on the datasheet for some reason.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This antenna type is called ceramic patch antenna.
If you google APM 2.5, you will find that it stands for ArduPilot Mega 2.5, which is a drone autopilot system, for which this GPS-receiver board (designator GY-GPS6MV2 on the PCB) is probably designed.
Yes, it is a U.FL connector, which is like you said also known as IPX (see this question: [Difference between Hirose U.FL and IPEX connectors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/317816/difference-between-hirose-u-fl-and-ipex-connectors))